# Laravel JSON field to Model Attributes for Data Table with Paginate

Tags: json, laravel, model

My code has Json Column named: json for Custom User Fields. I want my datatable to get that json column as individual fields for display. So essentially if my Model returns data as:

```
{
"id":1
"json" : {
    "name": "joe"    
    }
}
```

I need it to transform as (when I call Model::all() or Model::paginate() ):

```
{
"id":1
"name": "joe"  
}
```

So that my Datatable can show this data. I cannot add appends property to my model because this json is dynamic field and thus not known from the start. I tried these two variants:

```
public function getJsonAttribute($value)
{
    $json = json_decode($value);
    foreach ($json as $k => $v) {

        array_push($this->appends, $key);
        // or
        $this->attributes[$k] = $v;
    }
    return $json;
}
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 2):

In Your case this may be work. But its multi array means you can add one more foreach loop. then only work.

In your code **$key** is not defined

```
public function getJsonAttribute($value)
{
    $json = json_decode(json_encode($value),TRUE);
    $jsonArr = [];
    foreach ($json as $k => $v) {
        if($k == "id")
            $jsonArr['id'] = $v; 
        if($k == "json" && empty($v['name']) === false)
            $jsonArr['name'] = $v['name']; 
    }

    return (object)$jsonArr;
}
```

Comment: Oh Thanks about that typo on **$key**. Though your code does the default thing. Json would already return me an associative array of key => value pairs, so I don't need to convert it into an array again to return. I solved it by looping through collection and running a function on all instances of the model which runs the foreach loop I have applied to **getJsonAttribute**.